# Multiple aspect ratios in a single SVG

Tags: svg, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I'm looking for a way to create an responsive image using SVG, where some sections maintain their aspect ratio when re-sized and others are distorted. This pencil, for example, could be resized so the two ends stay the same shape and only the body is stretched, like the image below:
[image: illustration of preceding text]

I can do this in HTML5 using CSS3's border-image-slice, e.g.

```
    border-image-source: url("cropped-pencil_clipart.svg");
    border-image-slice: 25% 50% 25% 25% fill;
```

See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/QuoQue/pen/DaoKF) for an example. However I can't think of a way to achieve it in a 100% external SVG file that I can use as an image or object. In effect, I want the outer and middle elements to have preserveAspectRatio="none" and the left and right elements to have ="... slice". I know this isn't possible in "conventional" SVG 1.1 and I don't want to use JavaScript or ForeignObject because these would limit the ways I can use the external file.

Are there any clever workarounds that could selectively preserve the aspect ratio for individual parts of an image? I can re-create the source elements as pure paths if that's necessary. I've tried using patterns and even custom markers but without success so far. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: No direct solution. One way is to generate the pencil itself server side or write [your own function](http://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/JwkYm/12/) to change the pencil length. Masking the pencil into 3 parts and rebuilding it is another option

Comment: Like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/defghi1977/f4uctq5b/